# ALM: Should code reviews and unit tests be considered as backlog item tasks?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, scrum, azure-devops, alm

I've started using TFS as my ALM with a Scrum template. Should I include code reviews and unit tests as part of the tasks of the product backlog items (user stories) or should they be considered within (as part of) the development tasks?

[image: Unit test as a task of a product backlog item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests should be part of the development task -- you shouldn't be writing code, then writing tests for the code later. The tests should be written along with the code, and the code isn't done until it's tested.

For code review:

Again, code review isn't a separate task -- it's a requisite for a development task to be considered complete.

If you're using TFVC, install a code review check-in policy for TFVC and use the built in code review workflow.

If you're using Git, require pull requests and have the code reviewed when the pull request is submitted. In TFS 2015, you'll be able to use branch policies to enforce code reviews as well.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much. I just have one more doubt, is it correct to only check in when the task is complete or is it permitted to give partial check ins during the task? This comes to me because usually when you have not finished a task at the end of the day, you give a check in to prevent losing information, or simply to save the work you have done during the day. But on TFS online it happened to me that when I gave a check in and linked that check in to a task, it changed the task to DONE. What should be the right check in policy in this case?

Comment: When you link a work item in the "Pending Changes" window, you can choose whether to "Associate" or "Resolve". Just change it to "Associate" instead of "Resolve" and the task will remain open.

Comment: The practice for formalising your quality bar to include everything that you need is called Definition of Done, or Done.

Answer (score 1):

No, Code Review and Unit tests are not backlog items, not even a sprint task, those are development tasks.

I would recommend you to create the Definition of Done for your team, i.e. you can write common tasks that needs to be accomplished by the team to consider the story or defect done.

For example:
- Feature is coded, submitted to the repository and code review is done.
- Implementation is compliant with standards of coding.
- Unit Test cover primary functionality
- ....

You can share this to your team and keep improving it as the project continues. The DoD of my team has almost 30 items. That would be great to keep DoD in a common place, maybe wiki or in your workstation.

Answer (score 1):

In Agile methods, code Review and unit tests are indeed not Product Backlog items and should not be in the Product Backlog. However it is completely understandable and normal to incorporate those tasks into a Sprint Backlog.

To rephrase the Scrum Manual: " 
The Sprint Backlog is the set of Product Backlog items selected for the Sprint plus a plan for delivering the product Increment and realizing the Sprint Goal. 
The Sprint Backlog is a forecast by the Development Team about what functionality will be in the next Increment and the work needed to deliver that functionality"

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be part of user stores. In my opinion, they should be included as part of definition of done. When the feature is delivered -  the delivered should means that not only functional part is completed but all the tests are completed as well.